# Trying to create a 16x16 grid of divs using jQuery but divs keep overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a small project for an online course and I need to create a 16x16 grid of divs using jQuery to manipulate the DOM. Problem is, the divs are overlapping, how do I fix this? I'm a beginner so please be very critical of my work, it would be a huge help, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="EASP.css">
<head>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="EASP.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

#container {
    background-color: red;
    height: 192px;
    width: 192px;
}
.unit {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>");
    for(var x = 0; x < 2 x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
            unit.appendTo('container');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, EASP.js is the bit of code with jQuery in it. EASP.css is the CSS bit, EASP.html is the HTML bit.

Comment: When you say "*the divs are overlapping*" do you mean that you can only see one `.unit` element? Because that script creates one `unit` variable and then continually reappends that same created element multiple times: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pv80g61f/1/). If you use `clone()`, then it seems to work: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pv80g61f/2/). Also, there's a syntax error in your outer `for` loop (you should have a semi-colon between the `2` and the `x++`), as well as the need for `'#container'` instead of `'container'`.

Comment: Also, `unit.appendTo('container');` should change to `unit.appendTo('#container');` There's no `<container>` on your html

Comment: Yes, I can only see one . unit element so I assumed they were overlapping/stacking. I thought it might be doing that, however I also thought that .appendTo inserted code into the DOM, dare I say, "permanently"?

Comment: Jeez how did I miss that, fuyushimoya. Thank you.

Comment: why do you need nested loops?

Comment: because the first loop will be for the rows and the second loop will be for the columns. every loop in the "x" loop is followed by 16 loops in the "y" loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems are:

1. The CSS selector should be `#container` since you are referring it
   by ID.
2. Also, there is missing a `semicolon` in your first loop
3. And, `div.unit` should be defined inside the second for as in every loop you want to add a new `DIV` element:

After applying those changes, this code should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
            var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>");
            unit.appendTo('#container');
        }
    }
});
```

See **[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unyyk1pu/)**

Comment: If you're going to do it that way (don't, because it's relatively expensive and entirely unnecessary to re-create an element within the loop), why not simply chain it: `$('<div class="unit"></div>").appendTo('#container')`? Or even: `$('<div />', {'class' : 'unit'}).appendTo('#container')`?

Comment: @DavidThomas,  I definitely agree with you. But for the clarity of my third point, I preferred to leave as it is.

Comment: Thank you for listing the problems out so clearly, I appreciate it. The third point is very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ge8zd3jv/2/) is a working example. And here is just the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    background-color: red;
    height: 192px;
    width: 192px;
}

.unit {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    float: left;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
            $("<div>").addClass("unit").appendTo("#container");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The  elements are not overlapping. What happened is that you only created one  and appended it to the container twice in the loop. Naturally, only one  shows up because only one  was made.

Create and append the  in the for loop.
You must also fix some syntax errors in your original code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    for(var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
            var unit = $("<div class='unit' style='position:absolute'></div>");
            unit.appendTo('#container', {left: });
        }
    }
});
```

Seeing how you have a nested loop, I assume you are trying to make a grid matrix. This code will not make a x by y grid because of the floating and collapsing of the html elements. To properly create a grid, you must specify the x and y position using a absolute positioning style and multiply the count by the  width. It really depends though because you can just as easy fill up your main container without doing this as well.

Comment: Ohhh I see, by putting it in the loop, a new one is created alongside the .appendTo. Thank you!!